# How to reload custom lightning component in a lightning page tab every time I click on the tab?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have one lightning component named "Add/Edit Invoice Line Item" (as seen on screenshot)
I want to reload this component every time a user clicks on this tab.
Is there any way or event which can be used to handle this?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried the refresh view event but that does not work if I do any change in related list records tab and also tried the following events but didn't work. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_lightning.htm

Comment: Did you try a change handler? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm On what kind of changes should your component refresh?

Comment: you can achieved by using `workspaciAPI`  if you can post your component code, it' ll help us to  give exact solution to you

Comment: Hey Sadanadamud1 , I have tried using WorkspaceAPI events but those are not working here, I think that works with the Lightning console not within a lightning page.

Answer (score 1):

lightning:tab by default will load only 1st time when it gets focus - there-by rendering the content/component in its body. Even when you navigate away from that tab, the content will just be hidden but not unrendered.

Workaround:
aura:if will render/unrender content in it depending on the condition. So use aura:if inside each tab. The condition can be {!v.selectedTabId=='tab1'}. You can set the selectedTabId by using onactive on lightning:tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

I have searched for the solution for 2 days (asked multiple people and checked documentation) but couldn't find anything.
So I have added an idea for salesforce to provide developers with Accessible Lightning Events from Lightning Page.
If you think this Idea can be useful to you as a developer the please upvote.

Idea: Accessible Lightning Events from Lightning Page. [(https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZbzQAG)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZbzQAG)

Thanks